# embedding finite CW-complex into the euclidean space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

how can I show that any finite CW-space can embedded into an euclidean space of some dimension? Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4524/1/4524.pdf

Comment: This is proved in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" corollary A.10. Voted to close.

Answer (score 7):

If your finite CW-complex is of topological dimension $n$, then it is an $n$-dimensional compact metric space, thus, by the The Menger-Nöbeling theorem (1932), it can be embedded in ${\mathbb R}^{2n+1}$. In this theorem $2n+1$ is the lowest possible dimension, since there exist $n$-dimensional simplicial complexes that cannot be embedded in ${\mathbb R}^{2n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, any simplicial complex can be realized as a subset of the simplex in $\mathbb{R}^V$ (where $V$ is the number of vertices). But a CW complex can only be embedded up to homotopy, it seems (see the answer to your duplicate question on math.stackexchange)

Comment: As long as $X$ is a separable metrizable space of finite dimension $n$, space $X$ can be **topologically** embedded in $\mathbb R^{2\cdot n+1}$. (Thus Wlodek's pointer is correct, and the author of the *QUESTION* doesn't even need to restrict the CW-complex to be finite--separability would be enough to assure embeddability).